# Nuxt layouts/error.vue does not work in production build the way it does in development

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

Referencing the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/layouts/#error-page), i added `layouts/error.vue` for a page handling errors. Testing this in development (`npm run dev`), everything works as expected. But when I do `npm run build` and then `npm start`, The error page is not rendered when i test throwing an exception in production.

I'm using `SSR` but I don't see anything in the docs that suggest `layouts/error.vue` wont work for `SSR` or universal sites. There is a similar [issue reported](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6869). The person made a work around for their use case. But the issue (Main error handler is ignored and exception ends up logged to console instead of rendering error page) was not resolved.

In development the error page is shown if I throw a test error with `throw new Error()` on button click. But in production, the error just goes to console and the error page is not rendered. The only way i can make it work in production without changing a lot of other code is to set `debug: true` in `nuxt.config.js`.

Also note that `error.vue` works perfectly in production too for 404 pages. But it doesn't work like it does in development if I `throw new Error` in a production build from a component.

You can easily reproduce this by generating a new nuxt app with `npm create nuxt-app <app name>` . Here are the settings I choose:
[image]

Add the following to `layouts/error.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>You are in layouts/error.vue</h1>
    <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
    <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
    <pre v-if="error.statusCode !== 404">{{ error }}</pre>
    <nuxt-link to="/">Click to visit Home page</nuxt-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    error: {
      type: [Object, Error],
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  layout: 'blog', // you can set a custom layout for the error page
}
</script>
```

Then add `<button @click="throwE">Click to throw error</button>` to `components/Logo.vue` and add the following script to the page:

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    throwE() {
      throw new Error('Error thrown by button click')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Click the button in development, and it works as expected. Click the button in production and `error.vue` is not rendered.

Are the docs wrong? Is this a bug? Why does `error.vue` work as expected while in development but not in production build when throwing a error?

Comment: Hi, what is your production environment exactly? Is it Github Pages, Netlify, a pretty classic server? I'm asking because the first two could have their own way of handling 404 errors (not sure though)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. the only way I got it to work the same both in dev and prod, was to use this.$nuxt.error({ message: 'Error' }) instead of throw new Error('Error')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force any feature to launch a Nuxt error, you need to call the `error` function. This function is available in the nuxt context.

(Example from doc)

```js
export default {
  async asyncData({ params, $http, error }) {
    const id = params.id

    try {
      // Using the nuxtjs/http module here exposed via context.app
      const post = await $http.$get(`https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts/${id}`)
      return { post }
    } catch (e) {
      error(e) // Show the nuxt error page with the thrown error
    }
  }
}
```

Doc: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers/#using-page-parameters-for-your-api-query

Then if your app is universal (target = 'static') you must set into **nuxt.config.file** the fallback for your error page:

```js
  generate: {
    fallback: true
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

I suspect your problem may be solved by adding the following to your nuxt.config.js file:

```
generate: {
    fallback: "404.html"
},
```

Or alternatively:

```
generate: {
    fallback: true
  }
```

Your problem and solution are discussed on the following webpages:

https://nuxtjs.org/faq/netlify-deployment#how-to-deploy-on-netlify-

https://dev.to/debs_obrien/when-netlify-gives-you-that-404-page-4561

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/966